# Angular2 material dialog self close

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I used angular2 material `MdDialog` to show a form.

When user submits the form, a request is sent to the backend and if the request is successful, I need to close the dialog. If backend request failed, I need to keep the dialog open.

I can close the dialog by using a button like below.

```
<button md-raised-button md-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
```

But, in this case, I only need to close the dialog only if the backend request is successful, so I need a way to programmatically close the dialog.

The component which is shown inside the dialog doesn't have the dialog ref, and I don't know any other way to self close the dialog from the component.

Is there any way I an close the dialog from within the component inside the dialog?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you wanna close it from the dialog:

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>){ }

closeDialog(){
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

---

If you wanna close it from the parent of the dialog:

```
constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog){}

//anywhere
let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(MyDialogComponent);
dialogRef.close();
```

Comment: this gives error when I open it as normal screen.. instead of modal..any idea?

Comment: After close the dialog parent component content is not visible.What could be the reason?

Comment: @ManirajSS you have to pass in the data of the dialog to the `close()` method.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the accepted answer

```
this.dialogRef.close();
```

closes the dialog. But most of the time we want the response from server to be rendered immediately without refreshing the page. To do that, we pass the response as an arugument to the close method as shown below

```
this.dialogRef.close(response);
```

If you do this, you don't need to do the event emmiter approach found in the docs which is

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="response" cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>
```

since it closes the dialog before the asynchronous operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

This following works fine for me

`this.matDialog.closeAll();`

Comment: Useful then the content of the dialog comes from the child!